# What did I need do to get multi value of href in jquery, no change in html?

Tags: php, jquery, html, href

I am try to get multi href value in jquery. If I clicked the apple, it shows apple on the bottom, and click banana, it show apple and banana. If I clicked apple again, apple disappear. However, I only can get the value whichever I click the link. Click the Run Code Snippet to see.  The challenge here was no change in html, don't touch the html code, only do change in jquery. is that possible to do what I want? Appreciate.

```js
$('a').on('click', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
 
   var href=$(this).attr('href');
      $("#results").html(href);
   
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <a href='apple' class="selectedtag">apple</a>
    <a href='berry' class="selectedtag">berry</a>
    <a href='banana' class="selectedtag">banana</a>
    <a href='pineapple' class="selectedtag">pineapple</a>
     <div id="results" name="results" ></div>

  </html>
```

Comment: Sounds like you want to `append()` to `#results` rather than setting its `html()`.

Answer (score 0):

here is your solution without changing html. 
http://jsbin.com/pamipesemo/3/edit

```
var resultArray = [];
$("a").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  if(resultArray.indexOf(href) != -1)
    {
      resultArray.splice(resultArray.indexOf(href), 1);
    }
  else{
    resultArray.push(href);
  }

  var result = resultArray.join(' ');
  $("#results").text(result);

});
```

Comment: Thank you! I have to say that you are genius! If you can, can you explain what is !=-1, why is -1, but not 0. Sorry, i am not a professional developer.

Comment: Hi when you search in array through indexOf(), it return -1 if no value found or give exact array position if found. that's why its -1 and  != means not equal to.